# Hazelcast jet flatMap says: These transforms have nothing attached to them: [flat-map]

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

I am trying to filter BatchStage but it is not working it is giving me below error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: "filterFn" must be serializable
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.util.Util.checkSerializable(Util.java:203)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.pipeline.ComputeStageImplBase.attachFilter(ComputeStageImplBase.java:154)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.pipeline.BatchStageImpl.filter(BatchStageImpl.java:105)
    at com.aiv.hazelcast.JoinData.join(JoinData.java:121)
    at com.aiv.hazelcast.Application.lambda$1(Application.java:93)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
    at com.aiv.hazelcast.Application.runProcess(Application.java:90)
    at com.aiv.hazelcast.Application.setUp(Application.java:44)
    at com.aiv.hazelcast.Application.main(Application.java:26)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.hazelcast.com.fasterxml.jackson.jr.ob.impl.DeferredMap
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1193)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1387)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1579)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1536)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1444)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1187)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:353)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.util.Util.checkSerializable(Util.java:201)
```

My code is as below what wrong am I doing?

This is working one:

```
BatchStage<Object> bd = jdbcBatchStageData.flatMap(list -> Traversers.traverseArray(list.toArray()));
         bd.filter(k -> { 
             
             return true;
             
         }).writeTo(Sinks.logger());
```

This is not working weird :

```
BatchStage<Object> bd = jdbcBatchStageData.flatMap(list -> Traversers.traverseArray(list.toArray()));
         bd.filter(k -> { 
             
             return filterItems((List<Map<String, Object>>)rules.get("criteria"));
             
         }).writeTo(Sinks.logger());

public static boolean filterItems(List<Map<String, Object>> innerrules) {
    return true;
}
```

I don't know why it is not working, help me out.
If I remove filter it is working properly but I need to filter.

Comment: Isn't there another `flatMap` in your pipeline? The one you shared looks ok. Can you share the whole pipeline? If you have no other `flatMap` stage, I'd say it's a bug, file it.

Comment: no there is only one flatMap that I am using here. Instead if I directly return true it is working. Check I have edited question.

Comment: This is indeed weird, if there's no other difference than the return value from the `filter` lambda. Can you please try to create a reproducer? Isn't there any other exception logged that might cause this, such as a serialization exception?

Comment: Oh yes there is one exception that I missed, question edited

Answer (score 1):

We serialize the `Pipeline` and send it to the cluster for execution. This means that all fields must be serializable. In your case, your lambda captures some local variable that is not serializable. Likely it is the `rules` map. You need to copy the data to some serializable structure, e.g. to a `HashMap`. Or replace like this:

```java
Criteria criteria = (List<Map<String, Object>>) rules.get("criteria");
bd.filter(k -> { 
    return filterItems(criteria);
})
```

This will work, if `Criteria` is serializable and `filterItems` method is static - if it's not, also `this` (the containing class instance) will be captured.

BTW, I wonder why you don't use `k` in your filter implementation at all, this is likely a mistake.

Comment: No it's still showing same error, and criteria is dynamic List<Map> object without fix fields and yes I am using k but here for example I haven't used it.